# Определить букву, после удаления которой, слово станет палиндромом, если такой буквы нет - вывести 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно Определить букву, после удаления которой, слово станет палиндромом, если такой буквы нет - вывести 0
Вот что написал :

```
from collections import deque

word = input('Enter a word\n')

def palindrome(word):
    dq = deque(word)
    while len(dq) > 1 :
        if dq.popleft() != dq.pop() :
            return dq.popleft().index
        if dq.pop() != dq.popleft() :
            return dq.pop().index
        else :
            return 0
print(palindrome(word), '\n')
```

Попробовал сделать через index, но в каждом случае он выводит 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример. Идея следующая: мы смотрим с двух сторон. Нашли пару не совпадающих символов. Проверим будет ли она палиндромом если убрать правый или левый символ.

```
def reverse(s):
    return s[::-1]


def isPalindrome(s):
    rev = reverse(s)
    if (s == rev):
        return True
    return False

def RemOneCharPal(str):
    low = 0
    high = len(str) - 1
    while (low < high):
        if (str[low] == str[high]):
            low += 1
            high -= 1
        else:
            if (isPalindrome(str[low+1:high+1])):
                return str[low]
            if (isPalindrome(str[low:high])):
                return str[high]
            return 0
    return 0
```